# Phoenix Framework websocket, setting check_origin at runtime

Tags: websocket, elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm using exrm as release manager

I have added a config in my prod.exs so I can retreive at runtime the environment variable 'check_origin'

```
config :my_app, check_origin: "${CHECK_ORIGIN}"
```

The issue is that, the websocket is configured at compile-time with

```
transport :websocket, Phoenix.Transports.WebSocket
```

So I can't do something like this :

```
transport :websocket, Phoenix.Transports.WebSocket, check_origin: Application.get_env(:my_app, :check_origin) |> Poison.decode!
```

Does anyone know how I can configure the websocket's transport at runtime, So I can use the environment variable (which is an encoded json)

Edit :

Here's what I already tried :

```
def start(_type, _args) do                                                                                                                                                                                                          
    import Supervisor.Spec, warn: false                                                                                                                                                                                               

    c_o = ((Application.get_env(:my_app, :check_origin) || "true") |> Poison.decode!)                                                               
    Application.put_env(:my_app, MyApp.Endpoint, Application.get_env(:my_app, MyApp.Endpoint) ++ [check_origin: c_o])  
......
```

Comment: I think Distillery has `REPLACE_OS_VARS=true` env var that you can set and it will replace env vars in the configuration on start up. I tried looking for something similar in exrm and all I can see is here (seems to be called `RELX_REPLACE_OS_VARS`): https://github.com/bitwalker/exrm/blob/417286f13aebb4a19bee39bfdb4cd44b41d18f5f/priv/rel/files/boot

Comment: Yup, at startup... my issue is that the transport setting of the websocket is at compile-time...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work:

First, skip `check_origin` in the `transport` line:

```
transport :websocket, Phoenix.Transports.WebSocket
```

Then, in your Endpoint module's `init/2` function, add this at the start:

```
config = Keyword.put(
  config,
  :check_origin,
  Application.get_env(:my_app, :check_origin) |> Poison.decode!
)
```

In a brand new Phoenix 1.3 app, I get this:

```
iex(1)> FooWeb.Endpoint.config :check_origin
false
```

After adding the following to `init/2`:

```
config = Keyword.put(config, :check_origin, true)
```

I get:

```
iex(1)> FooWeb.Endpoint.config :check_origin
true
```

According to the [source code](https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix/blob/master/lib/phoenix/socket/transport.ex#L427), the origin check should fall back to this config variable if it can't find `check_origin` in the transport's config. Let me know if it works though, I haven't tested the functionality.

Comment: Actually, I already tried that... using Application.put_env in :my_app Endpoint config... it doesn't seems to fallback on the Endpoint check_origin although the check_origin is correctly set to in the Endpoint config afterwards... Or I missed something, I'll retry just for my piece of mind

Comment: In my Edit, is what I already tried... seems to be the same idea, not working though :-(

Comment: Will it change anything If I do that in the endpoint's init ?

Comment: It should. The problem with your code was that the call to `transport` was evaluated at compile time. `init/2` however is meant to change config at boot time.

Comment: hmmm, Is `init/2` on phoenix v1.3 ? I do not seems to have that in 1.2.4

Comment: Yes, it is new in 1.3.

Comment: I'll mark the solution as valid since it probably works on 1.3, I'll try to find a solution for 1.2